# Weird character on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i proceed XML, sometime i get XML parsing error because of weird character.

something like this character : Ã¢â¬â¢

how can i filter this character using PHP?

or can i clean database, and remove those weird character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to your database into UTF-8 charset and you don't have anymore strange chars or put strings between `<![CDATA[]]>`

Comment: If your connection already into utf-8 and your xml output too, try using `utf_decode()` on each non-tag ouput.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query just after connecting to your database:

```
set names 'utf8';
```

Also use same charset for writing your xml.

Comment: i already do that. but still no luck. those character still appear.

Answer (score 0):

It's a right single quote, encoded as UTF-8 and misinterpreted as CP1252, then re-encoded as UTF-8 and again misinterpreted as CP1252. Sounds like you are having major charset issues. That may be why it isn't fixed when you set the charset to UTF-8: it's only fixed halfway.